# Error when importing lxml objectify and etree in x86_64 Cent OS

Tags: python, centos, virtualenv, lxml

I have a CentOS setup with virtualenv and python 2.7. I installed lxml using:

```
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fPIC -lgcrypt -ldl -lgpg-error -lrt" STATIC_DEPS=true pip2.7 install lxml
```

and it compiles and installs without errors.

However, my app breaks when lxml.objectify is imported. Investigating the issue further i realized its both  lxml.objectify and lxml.etree that cannot be imported. The error I get from objectify is:

```
>>> from lxml import objectify
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /var/htdocs/plus.dev/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/objectify.so:     undefined symbol: lzma_auto_decoder
```

and from etree:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /var/htdocs/plus.dev/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol: lzma_auto_decoder
```

I googled around and uninstalled xz-devel as prescribed in some forums but I still get the same error and its frustrating.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this after a lot of searching. This error was brought about by having 32bit compiled python packages and 64bit compiled python packages conflicting. Get a more detailed description plus the solution here https://github.com/0xdata/h2o/wiki/Installing-python-2.7-on-centos-6.3.-Follow-this-sequence-exactly-for-centos-machine-only